# android collapses so we restart everyday

Tags: android, garbage-collection, ram, garbage

Guys I have an application that works on the tablet.That is a smart house application.I root the tablet because I want to forbid the customers to use anything else but application on the tablet.Application is always visible and working non stop on the screen whenever tablet is on.But there is a problem.The problem is when application running about 1 day sometimes 2 days tablet collapses.That's why it needs to be restarted each time when that happens.I think it might be a problem of ram aka main memory.I just wonder about your thought.If I use garbage collector or some ram cleaner or ram expander, will it be a solution for me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there any crash log to provide more insight into your problem??

Comment: Please post logs, without those any answer we give will be speculative. As a side note, you might consider running this in Kiosk mode (see tutorials on that) rather than rooting the device.

Comment: Thanks for the answers I'll post logs if I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem appears to be a memory leak in your application.

Since this is a complex issue to identify and/or resolve, you could try some common tools to aid you, such as:

- https://medium.com/freenet-engineering/memory-leaks-in-android-identify-treat-and-avoid-d0b1233acc8#.z178mon4s
- http://android-developers.blogspot.ch/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html
- https://github.com/square/leakcanary

Comment: I agree, this does sound suspiciously like a memory leak but it's difficult to tell for sure without logs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I'll try this.